# Receiving Error message: JSONDecodeError when attempting to use API

Tags: python, json, curl

I am following along with Python for Data Analysis and am on Chapter 6 looking at using APIs.
I wish to connect to sources provided by National Grid on their Data Portal. They provide a number of URLs (e.g. several found here, https://data.nationalgrideso.com/ancillary-services/obligatory-reactive-power-service-orps-utilisation). I want to read these directly into pandas rather than download the Excel/csv file and then open that.

I am receiving the error message
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
after attempting the following:

```
import requests
import codecs
import json

url = 'https://data.nationalgrideso.com/backend/dataset/7e142b03-8650-4f46-8420-7ce1e84e1e5b/resource/a61c6c26-62ec-41e1-ae25-ed95f4562274/download/reactive-utilisation-data-apr-2020-mar-2022.csv'
resp = request.get(url)
decoded_data = codecs.decode(resp.text.encode(), 'utf-8-sig')
data = json.loads(decoded_data)
```

I understand that I need to use `'utf-8-sig'` due to a particular BOM appearing on the first line otherwise.

I have looked at answers regarding the same error message but nothing is working for me at present. The API is working in the browser and I am receiving a response of 200 and data is being returned. Perhaps I am missing something more fundamental in the approach?

Comment: It looks like the data is csv, why are you treating it as json? Since you are using Pandas, you can just pass it the url : `df = pandas.read_csv(url)`

Comment: Thank you, so I was being a bit dense and the answer was right in front of me then. Your answer worked.